# Why is the wrong index assigned?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**CODE:**

```
    handleDeleteClick: function(index) {
        var newRecipesArray = this.state.recipesArray;
        newRecipesArray.splice(index-1,1);
        this.setState({
            recipesArray: newRecipesArray
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        var i = 0;
        var that = this;

        var recipes = this.state.recipesArray.map(function(item) {
            i++
            return (
                <div key={"div"+i} className="table">
                    <Recipe key={i} name={item.name} ingredients={item.ingredients} />
                    <button key ={"edit"+i} onClick={() => { that.handleEditClick(i)}} className="btn edit btn-primary">Edit</button>
                    <button  key ={"delete"+i} onClick={() => { that.handleDeleteClick(i)}} className="btn delete btn-danger">Delete</button>
                </div>
            );
        });

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>React.js Recipe Box</h1>
                <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleClick}>Add Recipe</button>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th>RECIPES</th>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                {recipes}
                { this.state.adding ? <AddRecipe handleClose={this.handleClose}  handleAdd={this.handleAdd} /> : null }
                { this.state.editing ? <EditRecipe currentIndex = {this.state.currentIndex} handleClose={this.handleClose}  handleEdit={this.handleEdit}/> : null }
            </div>
        );
    },
});
```

---

**SITUATION:**

When I click on delete, it's always the last element that is deleted instead of the one that should be linked to that specific delete button.

Where does the mistake lie and how do I fix it ?

Comment: do your recipes have some unique ID? the index is a poor choice for a key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map gives index as the second parameter so do not need a separate index variable. Also you don't need a key for all the elements but only the parent element

```
handleDeleteClick: function(index) {
        var newRecipesArray = this.state.recipesArray;
        newRecipesArray.splice(index,1);
        this.setState({
            recipesArray: newRecipesArray
        });
    },
    render: function() {

        var that = this;

        var recipes = this.state.recipesArray.map(function(item, i) {

            return (
                <div key={"div"+i} className="table">
                    <Recipe name={item.name} ingredients={item.ingredients} />
                    <button onClick={() => { that.handleEditClick(i)}} className="btn edit btn-primary">Edit</button>
                    <button  onClick={() => { that.handleDeleteClick(i)}} className="btn delete btn-danger">Delete</button>
                </div>
            );
        });
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Sadly, this didn't change anything to the behaviour of the component. The last elements are still the ones getting deleted although I click on the first delete button :/ What could cause this ?

Comment: Can you log and see the index in the function

Comment: Fixed ! Perfect :D